# Dowloading a file through flask + python

Tags: python, flask

On a server, I have some files that are generated hourly. Users in the UK will need access to these files. The problem is that I do not want to give them SSH or VPN access. Instead, I am trying to create a web application that will accomplish this task. So, I have decided to use flask.

So, which modules should I use that can accomplish this task. My requirement is to fetch the information from the server through ssh, and then allow user to download that information from the flask application.

Comment: As much as I love flask, what about the old skool solution of Apache + rsync? You could rsync the files over via SSH into Apache's web directory. Apache would give you a very basic index page and the ability to download files. You could put it under HTTPS and password-protect it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

You can use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module to download a file with an external program. 
You can use [`sched`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) to schedule the event at some future time, though it's probably better to setup a `cron` script for fetching the files. You should look for resources online.

In your case, you can use `scp host@server:remotepath localpath` to fetch the script. Something like

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["scp", "host@server:remotepath", "localpath"])
print (open("localpath").read())
```